# How do you find the smallest difference in mapping elements of a Primary List to two Secondary Lists

Tags: algorithm, perl

I have 10 players on a team.
My team of players need to purchase a total of 10 bats and 10 balls.

They can purchase:

1. A bat and a ball
2. Two bats
3. Two balls
   They cannot buy 3 bats, or 3 balls, or any other combination. Two items only.

The Seller has 10 different balls, and 10 different bats, all with different prices.
Once 1 bat is sold, then that would be removed from the list.

The Buyer can go into debt.
The Seller does not have any change (even after a purchase).
If the Buyer spends 100 on a ball worth 10, he does NOT get 90 back.

I do have access to how much money each player has, as well as the value of how much the Seller will sell each bat and ball for.

```
Buyer - Name, Ball Purchase Price, Bat Purchase Price
Alpha   10 15
Bravo   20 20
Charlie 30 30
Delta   40 40
Echo    50 50
Foxtrot 60 60
Golf    70 70
Hotel   80 80
India   90 95
Juliett 99 99
```

```
Seller - Ball Name, Ball Price
A 10
B 20
C 30
D 40
E 50
F 60
G 70
H 80
I 90
J 99
```

```
Seller - Bat Name, Bat Price
A 99
B 95
C 80
D 70
E 60
F 50
G 40
H 30
I 20
J 15
```

In this example Alpha should purchase Ball-A and Bat-J, and Juliett should purchase Ball-J and Bat-A.

I am trying find an optimized way of figuring out which player should be buying which items to save the most money as a team, or for the team to be the least in debt.

**How do you find the smallest difference in mapping elements of a Primary List to two Secondary Lists?**
In a more complex scenario, how do I find out which Buyer should purchase which items?

In other examples, the seller might have a very expensive store where the players might have to go into debt.

Searching this type of question was difficult, as I am trying to find the smallest differences between my primary list, and two secondary lists, where the primary list can compare the same element twice.

Comment: I'm not sure about how the mechanic of not getting change works. If the buyers collectively have 20 bags of money, and there are 20 items, maybe we can just sort the money bags by worth, sort the items by cost, and match them up in order. There's a proof (by induction on the number of inversions) that this minimizes debt.

Comment: This problem doesn't necessarily have to be with a buyer and a Seller. It could be Baseball teamA vs Baseball teamB with Pitchers different pitches and hit % versus lefty or right handed hitters. 
I am trying to coordinate the closest matches between the primary list and two secondary lists with the smallest delta/difference.